# Azure VPN Site to Site VPN (Azure to Cisco)

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco, azure, site-to-site-vpn

I configured a VPN IP Sec tunnel from VPN gateway in Azure to Cisco Router to customer end.

1. created vpn gateway
2. created local gateway config and connected successfully to a cisco router at customer end
3. stood up a VM and connected to a VNET that belongs to the VPN gateway in Azure

Issue:
1. I cannot ping or access anything across VPN from the VM that is connected to the VNET connected to the VPN gateway.

Diagram:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhbB2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ping depends if you have ICMP enable in your network. I have setup a few Site-To-Site, though not Cisco, If the VPN connection is connected the VM should be able to connect to services inside your On-Premises network because Azure puts in routing automatically. Unless you have address spaces that are overlapping then traffic will not be sent over.

From your On-Premises to Azure you will have to make sure the routing for the address space is setup to sent traffic to Azure.